# Parsing values from string with pattern

Tags: c#, parsing

Is there any method or library with function that allows to perform such parsing from string:
Input: input string, in which I want to search, pattern for search (will describe later).
Output: array of strings

The pattern must be in format like:

`"Items: {0} in Boxes: {1}"`

So you should specify the places where output values must be.

Input and output examples using this pattern:

Input: `"Items Item 1, Item 2 in Boxes Box 1, Box 2"`

Output: `["Item 1, Item 2", "Box 1, Box 2"]`

I know that this is not a hard function to write, but I'm searching for a existed solution in a standard .NET library or for a custom and fast solution instead.

Comment: you can have a look at this link https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8yttk7sy(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: No, there is no such method in the framework which does it for you. You either have to use string methods or regex. _"I know that this is not a hard function to write"_ Yes, you need to do that.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 solutions I can think of: Using `Regex` or using `String` manipulation functions.

First approach with regex:

```
string text = "Items Item 1, Item 2 in Boxes Box 1, Box 2";

var match = Regex.Match(text, "^Items(?: ([^,]*),?)* in Boxes(?: ([^,]*),?)*$");

System.Console.WriteLine("Items:");
foreach (Capture cap in match.Groups[1].Captures)
    System.Console.WriteLine(cap.Value); // -->Item1 and Item2

System.Console.WriteLine("Boxes:");
foreach (Capture cap in match.Groups[2].Captures)
    System.Console.WriteLine(cap.Value); // --> Box 1 and Box 2
```

Solution with classical string operations:

```
string text = "Items Item 1, Item 2 in Boxes Box 1, Box 2";

var allItems = text.Remove(text.IndexOf("in Boxes")).Remove(0, "Items ".Length);
var itemArray = allItems.Split(',');

var allBoyes = text.Remove(0, text.IndexOf("in Boxes")).Remove(0, "in Boxes ".Length);
var boxArray= allItems.Split(',');
```

Take care of the spaces left here, you still need to `.Trim()` the items.

What you use and what fits your problem best depends on the circumstances. I'd prefer the string solution as it's more readable and less error prone.